# AWS ActiveMQ fetch messages from a Consumer and send to a queue

Tags: python, activemq-classic, stomp, stomp.py

I am trying to fetch messages from a consumer and send it to a queue. For this I am using `Stomp.py` After going through articles and posts, I wrote below code:

```
import ssl
import stomp

stompurl = "xxxxxxxx.mq.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
stompuser = "stomuser"
stomppass = "password"


class MyListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    msg_list = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.msg_list = []

    def on_error(self, frame):
        self.msg_list.append('(ERROR) ' + frame.body)

    def on_message(self, frame):
        self.msg_list.append(frame.body)


conn = stomp.Connection(host_and_ports=[(stompurl, "61614")], auto_decode=True)
conn.set_ssl(for_hosts=[(stompurl, "61614")], ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
lst = MyListener()
listener = conn.set_listener('', lst)
conn.connect(stompuser, stomppass, wait=True)
# conn.send(body='Test message', destination='Test_QUEUE')
conn.subscribe('Test_QUEUE', '102')
print(listener.message_list)
import time; time.sleep(2)
messages = lst.msg_list
# conn.disconnect()
print(messages)
```

With this code I am able to send messages to `Test_QUEUE` but I can't fetch all messages from consumer. How can I pull out all messages from a consumer and post to a queue for processing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Python + STOMP expert, but in every other language I've used when you create an asynchronous (i.e. non-blocking) message listener as you have done then you must prevent your application from exiting. You have a `time.sleep(2)` in there, but is that realistically enough time to fetch all the messages from the queue?

It appears your application will exit after `print(messages)` which means that if you don't get all the messages during the `time.sleep(2)` then your application will simply terminate.